# Overriding a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Is it possible to override a function in JavaScript? In python for example I could do this in one file:

```
#file one.py
class Test:
    def say(self,word):
        pass
    def speak(self):
        self.say("hello")
```

Then in another file do this:

```
import one
class Override(one.Test):
    def say(self,word):
        print(word)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Override().speak()
```

This would may it print("hello") rather than passing because of the override.

Is there a JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: Can you write up a JavaScript example?

Comment: You mean inheritance? Javascript's inheritance is weird (it's prototypal as opposed to classical) but if you look up inheritance in Javascript you should find how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function Test() {}

Test.prototype.say = function (word) {
    alert(word);
}

Test.prototype.speak = function () {
    this.say('hello');
}

Test.prototype.say = function (word) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

the last assignment will override the say method on all Test objects. If you want to override it in an inheriting function (class):

```js
function Test() {}

Test.prototype.say = function (word) {
    alert(word);
}

Test.prototype.speak = function () {
    this.say('hello');
}

function TestDerived() {}

TestDerived.prototype = new Test(); // javascript's simplest form of inheritance.

TestDerived.prototype.say = function (word) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

if you want to override it in a specific instance of test:

```js
function Test() {}

Test.prototype.say = function (word) {
    alert(word);
}

Test.prototype.speak = function () {
    this.say('hello');
}

var myTest = new Test();

myTest.say = function (word) {
    console.log(word);
}
```